# Is there a way to install "Tablet Mode" in Debian MATE?

Tags: linux, debian, touchscreen, tablet

I want to install Debian 8.3 using the MATE desktop environment on my wife's 7" Android Tablet. Is there a way to make this "touch friendly"? From my understanding, the tablet screen is just a regular Wacom tablet. Can I install a driver that will identify the touch screen as a Wacom device?